# dynamic struts <html:option>

Tags: html, html-select, struts

How to write dynamic struts `<html:option>`, I'm doing as below

```
<logic:iterate id="data" name="sendEmailForm" property="eventList">
    <html:option value="<bean:write name="data" property="eventId"/>"/>
        <bean:write name="data" property="title"/>
    </html:option>
</logic:iterate>
```

but getting following error:

> JSPG0069E: Unmatched end tag found while parsing jsp. Expecting
>   logic:iterate found html:option at [87,130]

is there another way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok finally i found below for solution

```
<html:optionsCollection name="sendEmailForm" property="eventList" label="title" value="eventId" />
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<html:option property="title">
<html:optionsCollection name="sendEmailForm" label="title" value="eventId" />
<html:option>
```

1. #### html:option tag

   `property="?"` whatever you want to set  like if attribute is title and corresponding method (`getTitle()`, `setTitle(String title)` ) then `property= "title"`
2. #### html:optionsCollection tag

   - `name = "?"` whatever you have put in your request/session attribute
     like `(request Or session).setAttribute("sendEmailForm", ListArr);`
     then name="sendEamilForm"

     - `listArr` is array of object of bean ( may be formbean or simple pojofile/bean).
   - `label ="?"` what ever you want to show like if you have attribute `'title'` and 
     corresponding `setter(setTitle(String title)`) and `getter(getTitle()`) method then 
     `label="title"`
   - `value ="?"` what ever you want to put as value in option. you call your getter method 
     corresponding attribute like if you have attribute eventId and method ( 
     `setEventId(String eventId) , getEventId()` ) then `value="eventId"`